# How to copy files from gdrive to s3 bucket using google scripts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-apps-script

I created a Google Form with a linked Google Spreadsheet. I would like that everytime someone submits the form, the spreadsheet is copied to an s3 bucket in AWS. To do so, I just got started with Google Scripts. I managed to get the trigger part working on form submit but I am struggling to understand the readme of this [GitHub project](https://github.com/viuinsight/google-apps-script-for-aws) to upload to s3.

```
function setUpTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('copyDataS3')
  .forForm('1SK-2Ow63vs_TaoF54UjSgn35FL7F8_ANHDTOOiTabMM')
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}

function copyDataS3() {
  // https://github.com/viuinsight/google-apps-script-for-aws
  // I do not understand where should I place aws.js and util.js. 
  // Should I do File -> New -> Script file and copy paste the contents? Should the file be .js or .gs?
  S3.init("MY_ACCESS_KEY", "MY_SECRET_KEY"); 
  // if I wanwt to copy an spreadsheet with the following id, what should go into "object" below?
  var ssID = "SPREADSHEET_ID";
  S3.putObject(bucketName, objectName, object, region)
}
```

Comment: About `I would like that everytime someone submits the form, the spreadsheet is copied to an s3 bucket in AWS.`, Google Spreadsheet cannot be copied to the external storage as Google Spreadsheet. If you want to export it, it is required to convert to XLSX, PDF, CSV and so on which are not Google Spreadsheet. How about this?

Comment: Csv would also be fine! How would I do it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed the 2 modification patterns as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not the solution of your issue, I apologize.

Comment: eager to try it! where do I have to paste the contents of aws.js, util.js and s3.js. I tried creating a new script and copy pasting the contents but it gets saved as e.g. aws.js.gs

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about `eager to try it! where do I have to paste the contents of aws.js, util.js and s3.js. I tried creating a new script and copy pasting the contents but it gets saved as e.g. aws.js.gs`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: I am trying to run the code but I need to install first the Github project. Reading the Github project readme but not clear to me how to set it up. Can you add it as steps to your solution?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I'm not sure about the pattern you want to use. When you use my answer, please copy and paste the scripts of https://github.com/viuinsight/google-apps-script-for-aws to the script editor and modify the script by my proposal. By this, you can use the modified script as the library. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

Comment: How can I change the default utf-8 encoding to ISO? I tried .setEncoding('ISO-8859-1') after .getValues() but it gives an error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `How can I change the default utf-8 encoding to ISO? I tried .setEncoding('ISO-8859-1') after .getValues() but it gives an error`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Yes, I have problems when parsing my csv because it contains characters like üöä which are not in UTF-8. I would like to change the encoding to ISO.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although, unfortunately, from your replying, I'm not still sure about the pattern you want to use, in your case, at pattern 2, when `var blob = Utilities.newBlob("", MimeType.CSV, "sample.csv").setDataFromString(csvData, "ISO-8859-1");` is used, what result will you get?

Comment: I get an error as csvData is not defined in pattern 2

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that from your replying, you are using the pattern 2. And, when you use `var blob = Utilities.newBlob("", MimeType.CSV, "sample.csv").setDataFromString(csvData, "ISO-8859-1");`, please set your CSV data to `csvData`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setdatafromstringstring,-charset) If you cannot understand about this, please add the detail information of your current situation in your question? By this, I would like to check it. If you cannot understand about my English. Please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to send Google Spreadsheet to s3 bucket as a CSV data using Google Apps Script.

### Modification points:

- When I saw [`google-apps-script-for-aws`](https://github.com/viuinsight/google-apps-script-for-aws) of the library you are using, I noticed that the data is requested as the string. I thought that in this case, your CSV data might be able to be directly sent. But for example, when you want to sent a binary data, it will occur an error. So in this answer, I would like to propose the modified script of 2 patterns.
- I thought that the situation might similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61491801). But I noticed that you are using the different library from the thread. So I post this answer.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, it supposes that only the text data is sent. It's like the CSV data in your replying. In this case, I think that it is not required to modify the library.

#### Modified script:

```
S3.init("MY_ACCESS_KEY", "MY_SECRET_KEY");  // Please set this.
var spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.
var region = "###"; //  Please set this.

var csv = SpreadsheetApp
  .openById(spreadsheetId)
  .getSheetByName(sheetName)
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues()  //  or .getDisplayValues()
  .map(r => r.join(","))
  .join("\n");
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(csv, MimeType.CSV, sheetName + ".csv");
S3.putObject("bucketName", "test.csv", blob, region);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, it supposes that both the text data and binary data are sent. In this case, it is required to also modify the library side.

#### For [`google-apps-script-for-aws`](https://github.com/viuinsight/google-apps-script-for-aws)

Please modify [the line 110 in `s3.js`](https://github.com/viuinsight/google-apps-script-for-aws/blob/master/s3.js#L110) as follows.

From:

```
var content = object.getDataAsString();
```

To:

```
var content = object.getBytes();
```

And, please modify [the line 146 in `s3.js`](https://github.com/viuinsight/google-apps-script-for-aws/blob/master/s3.js#L146) as follows.

From:

```
Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, content, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8));
```

To:

```
Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.MD5, content));
```

#### For Google Apps Script:

In this case, please give the blob to `S3.putObject` as follows.

Script:

```
S3.init("MY_ACCESS_KEY", "MY_SECRET_KEY");  // Please set this.
var fileId = "###";  // Please set the file ID.
var region = "###"; //  Please set this.

var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob();
S3.putObject("bucketName", blob.getName(), blob, region);
```

### References:

- [viuinsight/google-apps-script-for-aws](https://github.com/viuinsight/google-apps-script-for-aws)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [computeDigest(algorithm, value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computedigestalgorithm,-value)
- [PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html)

Comment: I have tried this method but got `AWS Error - BadDigest: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.`, I wonder if you have any clue of that.

Comment: @simonhb1990 I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this again.