# How to upload a sheet from Google Sheets to AWS S3 as a CSV using google Apps Script?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am reading in a google sheet data from many users they can hit submit on the sheet which triggers my Apps Script.
In my Apps Script I am transforming that data and writing it to another google sheet in the same format that I need it to be in for a csv.
Now I just want to upload that entire sheet to S3 as a csv. How can I do this in the Apps script?
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the suggestions provided by the user Tanaike in this link below.
[How to copy files from gdrive to s3 bucket using google scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054593/how-to-copy-files-from-gdrive-to-s3-bucket-using-google-scripts)
Thank you!