# Why does uploading a .csv file to S3 get converted to a json

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, google-apps-script, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3 using apps script.

I have been trying to use https://github.com/viuinsight/google-apps-script-for-aws

```
S3.init();
S3.putObject("bucket123", 'Tacofile.txt', content, 'ca-central-1')
```

1. I retrieve a file from Google Workspace, where 'Tacofile' is a .txt file
2. The file successfully loads to S3

The file, however, somehow gets converted to json? How to keep the file as a csv or is there a way to specify the MIME type somewhere before the upload?

thanks in advance

CB

Comment: Is `content` a file or a blob?  If not a blob `S3.putObject()` wraps it in a blob and `JSON.stringify()` it

Comment: 'content' is a file...is there a way to prevent S3.putOject() from wrapping it in a blob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@theWizEd thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I think I got this to work. I changed my source data so my download was done using:

```
object = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id).getBlob().getDataAsString();
```

i changed the section in line 106 below:

```
  if (notBlob) {
    object = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(object), "application/json");
    object.setName(objectName);
  }
var content = object.getDataAsString();  
var contentType = object.getContentType();
var contentMD5 = getContentMD5(content);
```

to the following

```
  if (notBlob) {
    //object = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(object), "application/json");
    //object.setName(objectName);
  }

  var content = object; 
  var contentType = MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT
  var contentMD5 = getContentMD5(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes use [File.getBlob()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getBlob()) `S3.putObject("bucket123", 'Tacofile.txt', content.getBlob(), 'ca-central-1')`

Comment: doesn't work. The problem is that even if you pass the content as a blob, it gets to this function     execute(region, action, method, bucketName, objectName, payload, headers) which eventually goes here: else if (typeof payload !== "string") {
        payload = JSON.stringify(payload); so it keeps changing the content to a JSON

Comment: Sorry, then I have no idea.

Comment: Take a look at this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054593/how-to-copy-files-from-gdrive-to-s3-bucket-using-google-scripts

Comment: thanks, I used this as reference but received the same error as in the comments 'AWS Error - BadDigest: The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.'  Also, I think this method wont work because no mater what version you convert the content to, it will eventually equate to the payload, which will always be converted, here..... if (typeof payload !== "string") {
        payload = JSON.stringify(payload);
        }
      var hashedPayload = Crypto.SHA256(payload);

Comment: Perhaps AWS storage is always JSON.  Have you tried to retrieve it and then JSON.parse()?